# Return a specific config variable using Heroku Toolbelt

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, config

This is a super-quick question that I couldn't find answered anywhere in the Heroku documentation.  Is there a one-line command like `heroku config` that can accept a variable name as an argument and return only the value of that specific config variable, rather than the entire list?

For example, something like:

```
heroku config:show CLOUDANT_URL
```

might return:

```
https://<username>.heroku:<password>@app<number>.heroku.cloudant.com
```

Or if not, does anyone know how to extend the Heroku Toolbelt and write one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a few months, but, per the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application),

```
$ heroku config:get GITHUB_USERNAME
joesmith
```

I just used it myself.  Hope that helps!